# How can I compute a spatial distance matrix based on control variables? (R)

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, hierarchical-clustering

I'm interested in computing a distance matrix with a custom distance function. This function should take into account spatial data and two control variables. This distance can be Euclidean. The details are following:

I have a data of sellers and buyers. This spatial dataset contains cities, coordinates, purchased quantity, and two control variables. I want to apply a Hierarchical Cluster to determine the "geographical markets", and for this, I'd like to compute a Distance Matrix that considers the two control variables I've mentioned.

I've tried this, but I'm not sure if I'm right with the object `W`.

```
# Sample data (because is private info).
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
cities <- c("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4", "City5")
seller_city <- sample(cities, n, replace = TRUE)
buyer_city <- sample(cities, n, replace = TRUE)
seller_coords <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(n, -80, 1), lat = rnorm(n, 40, 1))
buyer_coords <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(n, -80, 1), lat = rnorm(n, 40, 1))
quantity <- rpois(n, 10)
var1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) #First control variable.
var2 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) #Second control variable.
df <- data.frame(seller_city, buyer_city, seller_coords, buyer_coords, quantity, var1, var2)

# Compute distance matrix
city_dist <- distm(x =df[,c("lon", "lat")] ,
                             y = df[,c("lon.1", "lat.1")])
city_dist <- (city_dist - mean(city_dist)) / sd(city_dist) #Normalising, because its units differ to the control variables.
var_dist <- as.matrix(dist(df %>% select(var1, var2)))
var_dist <- (var_dist - mean(var_dist)) / sd(var_dist) #Normalising, because its units differ to the control variables.
W <- city_dist + var_dist # sum up


# Perform hierarchical clustering
hc <- hclust(as.dist(W), 
             method = "ward.D2")
```

The Idea is the compute the distance between cities *i* and *j* with the following formula:
[image: formula]

where *x* is the longitude, *y* is the latitude, *v1* is the control variable 1, and *v2* is the control variable 2.

Comment: Can you double-check if your formula is correct? Seemms like the last two terms in the sum are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the package `use_dist` with its function [`dist_make`](https://rdrr.io/cran/usedist/man/dist_make.html) to provide a custom distance function.

In your example, you could use it like this

```
library(usedist)

# ...

distance_function <- function (v1, v2) {
   (v1[["lon"]] - v2[["lon"]])**2
  +(v1[["lat"]] - v2[["lat"]])**2 
  +(v1[["var1"]] - v2[["var2"]])**2
  +(v1[["var1"]] - v2[["var2"]])**2;
}

# Collect the data points in one dataframe
df <- data.frame(seller_city, buyer_city, seller_coords, buyer_coords, quantity, var1, var2)

# Calculate the distance matrix
city_dist <- dist_make(df, distance_function)

# Apply hierarchical clustering
hc <- hclust(as.dist(city_dist), method = "ward.D2")
```

Using this approach you can use any arbitrary distance function that you would like. However, function you chose looks pretty similar to a standard euclidian distance, make sure to check if the indices are correct

Comment: thanks! Do you consider that standard euclidian distance is the proper method to compute the distance in this case? (when you have two cities with its coordinates and control variables).  Thanks in advance.